# Apollo angular client always using cache

Tags: angular, caching, apollo

I'm using apollo angular client with the InMemoryCache. I have some watchQuery's for which I want to disable caching. I've setup my client as follows:

```
link: httpLink.create({uri}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    ssrMode: false,
    ssrForceFetchDelay:0,
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        errorPolicy: 'ignore',
      },
      query: {
        fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
        errorPolicy: 'all',
      },
    }
```

and my watchQuery looks like this:

```
return this.apollo.watchQuery<TestAssetListQuery>({
        query: gql`
          query {
              testAssetList {
                name,
                path,
                size
              }
          }
        `,
        fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
      }).valueChanges;
```

Yet, every subsequent query is pulled from cache.

I'd appreciate any advice on how to force apollo not to cache my queries.

Comment: I should have known that I was doing something wrong. I'm using NGX datatables and was loading data with observable which wasn't updating the table data. I'm still working on getting it to work but it wasn't apollo client. It's working fine.

Comment: Ultimately my problem was with the way angular handles events. I was calling a function in component B from component A. Even though I was updating the underlying data for the datatable, the push event wasn't occurring. I still don't understand why, but moving the datatable into the same component that generated the original event(Component A) solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

*Since I have not enough reputation to comment. I will try to post it.*

Try using `network-only` instead of `no-cache`

Comment: Hi Anuj. I've tried nearly every option available and cannot get apollo to NOT use the cache. I've tried network-only and it still uses the cache. I feel like i'm doing something wrong as this should work, it's pretty critical, yet it I cannot get apollo to load from anywhere except cache, with the exception of an empty cache.